# How to query the architecture of a plug-in DLL on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, plugins

My app uses LoadLibrary to load plugins at run-time and users can accidentally try to load 64 bit plugins in the 32 bit version of my application.

It looks like the error code returned from LoadLibrary is not very descriptive (says "%1 is not a valid Win32 application").

I am looking for ways to figure out if the plugin dll file is built 32 or 64 bit so that I can notify the user in a user friendly way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to retrieve information about an image such as the one you are looking for, just use the [ImageHelp API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: The co-called Optional Header contains this information (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339(v=vs.85).aspx). See IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR_MAGIC field.

Comment: link you suggested doesn't work... is it a temporary problem?

Comment: IMAGE_FILE_HEADER (contained in IMAGE_NT_HEADERS, contained in LOADED_IMAGE) also appears to contain the architecture.

Comment: @Harry: you mean IMAGE_FILE_HEADER.Machine? This field contains "The architecture type of the computer" and not of the image. On the other side, IMAGE_FILE_HEADER.Characteristics field contains IMAGE_FILE_32BIT_MACHINE, which shows the target processor width.

Comment: If you want it, you can take a look at PeStudio (http://www.winitor.com) which shows how this information (support for 32/64 bit, and more..) is present at two locations in the image file.

Comment: IMAGE_FILE_HEADER.Machine is part of the file header; how can it possibly contain the architecture type of the current computer rather than that associated with the image file?

Comment: @Harry: "IMAGE_FILE_HEADER.Machine" > MSDN: "The architecture type of the computer. An image file can only be run on the specified computer". I guess this was a misunderstanding, this field contains, of course, the type architecture type as expected by the image file to run.